# How to move Word and PDF documents to Hadoop HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I want to copy/upload some files from a local system (a system not in Hadoop cluster) onto Hadoop HDFS. The local system can be Windows system too.

I tried with Flume spool directory. It works fine with Text files. For other docs, the mime type is getting corrupted.

Please let me know different approaches to load a file(s) to HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

```
 hadoop fs -copyFromLocal <localsrc> URI
```

Check Hadoop documentation: [copyFromLocal](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.18.3/hdfs_shell.html#copyFromLocal)

Keep in mind, Apache Flume wasn't created to copy `some` files.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `hadoop fs -put <localsrcpath> <hdfspath>`

This is one of the alternative to `copyFromLocal`

Comment: fs -put helps in moving files from local file system to hadoop. My problem how will I get files from outside this system say in enterprise document store onto hadoop. Should I manually upload them to Local file system and copy to HDFS? or any tools available that can help. This is where trying to use flume's HDFS sink.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to load docs from your Windows machine to linux machine using `filezilla` or other tool.

And then you need to use:

```
hadoop fs -put localsrcpath hdfspath
```

Following command will also work.

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal localsrcpath hdfspath
```

Answer (score 0):

Java code can do that easily. You don't require any tools for this. Check below, the piece of code that worked:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
try {
    conf.set("fs.defaultFS",<<namenode>>); //something like hdfs://server:9000 or copy from core-site.xml
    FileSystem fileSystem= FileSystem.get(conf);
    System.out.println("Uploading please wait...");
    fileSystem.copyFromLocalFile(false, new Path(args[0]), new Path(args[1].trim()));//args[0]=C://file or dir args[1]=/imported
```

Prepare jar out of this and run on any OS. Keep in mind you no need to
have Hadoop running in the machine, where you are going to run this
code. If you need any help, add comments.

Don't forget to add dnsresolver line where you run this code. Open `/drivers/etc/hosts` (for Windows)

```
hadoopnamenode ip-address
slavenode ip-address
```

Answer (score 0):

In hadoop 2.0 (YARN) you can do as follows to transfer local files to HDFS:

```
hdfs dfs -put "localsrcpath" "hdfspath"
```

where hdfs is the command located in the bin directory.